# ORA-12645 when enabling Oracle DB network encryption

Tags: networking, encryption, oracle10g, client, oracle9i

I have a Windows server running reporting with a Oracle 9.2.0.1.0 client and a Oracle DB server 10.2.0.5.
When i enable Network Encryption by adding the following to sqlnet.ora:

SQLNET.ENCRYPTION_SERVER = requested

SQLNET.CRYPTO_SEED = '$$$152363RRTTYWUWU****'

SQLNET.ENCRYPTION_TYPES_SERVER= (AES256)

SQLNET.EXPIRE_TIME = 10

ADR_BASE = /opt/oracle

I get an error "ORA-12645 Parameter does not exist".

How can I get network encryption working on this?

Comment: Please elaborate more on your question.

Comment: what do you want to know? I'm trying to enable Oracle Network Encryption between an Oracle 9i client to a 10g database server and i'm getting an ORA-12645 error.

Comment: I've found a workaround from the metalink notes which just fudges the issue by pointing the errors to $ORACLE_HOME/network/admin/sqlnet.log: